# About Jscolor how can I apply in different ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```html
<script>
  function update(jscolor) {

    // 'jscolor' instance can be used as a string

    document.getElementById('header').style.backgroundColor = '#' + jscolor

  }

  function update(jscolor) {

    // 'jscolor' instance can be used as a string

    document.getElementById('text').style.color = '#' + jscolor

  }
</script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="header">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="text">

   Customize Your Website

</a> 
  <input name="color2" class="jscolor form-control" onchange="update(this.jscolor)" value="#FFF">
```

Comment: You have two functions named the same. The second will be in force. . Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask and how to format your code. HINT: Give actual and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Use only one update function and add any id of element you want to be changed inside that function:

```
<script>
  function update(jscolor) {

    // 'jscolor' instance can be used as a string

    document.getElementById('header').style.backgroundColor = '#' + jscolor
    document.getElementById('text').style.color = '#' + jscolor

  }
</script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="header">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="text">

   Customize Your Website

</a> 
  <input name="color2" class="jscolor form-control" onchange="update(this.jscolor)" value="#FFF">
```